# How to make api call by passing basic auth in axios in react

Tags: api, axios

I have a api in which for login it works like this. To make api call i have to add authorization `basic auth` like this.

[image: Adding auth]

> And the body

[image: passing body]

But the problem is when i make api request through axios it always give me response error like this

```
Error: "Request failed with status code 401"
    createError createError.js:17
    settle settle.js:19
    handleLoad xhr.js:60
```

I made request something like this.

```
//TODO: AUTH Actions
export const login = (username, password) => (dispatch) => {
    //User Loading:
    dispatch({ type: USER_LOADING });
    //Make API Call here

    console.log('featch adata', data);
    axios.post('https://api.smartocart.com/oauth/token', {
        data: {
            username: username,
            password: password,
            grant_type: 'password',
        },
        auth: {
            username: 'topseller',
            password: 'topseller'
        }
    })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log('Then response', res)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    // console.log('Action login', username, password);

}
```

Comment: see your developer tools network tab and check the request body and headers. is it same as that in postman.

Comment: Seems like second param should be just request body and third param should be config(auth etc).

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config-1

Comment: @ssk i did not get this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned try the config object as third param to .post function, Request post body should be the second param.
https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config-1

You are trying something like `axios.post(url, config)` but such a function is not there. You should use `axios.post(url, data, config)`

```
axios.post('https://api.smartocart.com/oauth/token', 
         {
            username: username,
            password: password,
            grant_type: 'password',
         }, 
         {
           auth: {
             username: 'topseller',
             password: 'topseller'
           }
         }
        ).then((res) => {
            console.log('Then response', res)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
```